# Meteor Session setPersistent

Tags: javascript, meteor

How can I get `Session.setPersistent` to work in an old Meteor code which used to work 7 years ago, but now there is a browser error

> Session.setPersistent is not a function

With these errors when trying to add this package to make it work.

```
    PS C:\Users\AAA\Documents\meteor\apps\ais2> meteor add ando:persistent-session
     => Errors while adding packages:

    While selecting package versions:
    error: Potentially incompatible change required to top-level dependency: jquery 1.11.11, was 3.0.0.
    Constraints on package "jquery":
    * jquery@1.11.9 || 3.0.0 <- blaze 2.3.4 <- accounts-base 1.6.0
    * jquery@1.0.0 <- ando:persistent-session 0.2.1
    * jquery@1.0.0 <- amplify 1.0.0 <- ando:persistent-session 0.2.1

    To allow potentially incompatible changes to top-level dependencies, you must pass --allow-incompatible-update on the
    command line.
```

Comment: Can you post your `meteor list`? Do you have https://github.com/cult-of-coders/meteor-persistent-session added to your project?

Comment: Sorry, missed to see that you said which package you are trying to use. Well, that one doesn't seem to install. Maybe try the original `meteor add cultofcoders:persistent-session`.

Comment: I first tried the original as you suggested but it gave the same error. However I tried it again upon you request which still gave the same errors.